# Where does HaShem stands and in which council?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, commentaries, tehilim-psalms, language

Psalm 82 teaches that Elohim (אלהים) stands (נצב to position oneself) within the council/congregation (עדת-אל) of El, among/amidst (בקרב) elohiem (אלהים) He judge (ישפט).

Someone told me to look at a parallel passage from Psalm 89 which according to this person places Elohim in the holy assembly - or assembly of holy ones (בקהל קדשים). He also pointed out that this Psalm continues stating: Who in the clouds/skies (בשהק) can be compared to HaShem? Who is like HaShem among the (בני אלים) sons of Elim. (A) El dreaded in the great council of holy ones (בסוד קדשים רבה).

He claimed that the council talked about is 
in heaven, not on earth where the Jewish judges are. Additionally, there would be no text in the Tenach that has a council of human Israelite judges who are assigned to judge the nations of the earth.

But I noticed different words being used here, namely: עדת-אל v.s. בקהל קדשים and סוד קדשים רבה
Besides those I found אלהים v.s. בני אלים

So two questions: first of all what do these different terms mean (how to define them and to distinguish one from the other); and to whom do each of those refer? 
Secondly I would like to know how to interpret these verses I quoted, where does HaShem stand?

Comment: Do you ask that *before* you read the commentors on those Psukim or *after*?